# Is it possible to turn off the enforced vertical alignment in clojure-mode?

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 25.1, with the latest stable release of clojure-mode. When clojure-mode (not in other major modes like js2-mode) is turned on, everything is strictly aligned, no extra whitespace is allowed before any forms. For example,

```
(def
 last (fn ^:static last [x]
        (if (next x)
          (recur (next x))
          (first x))))
```

I can't insert a space (automatically removed after insertion) before the first non-whitespace character on each line. This kind of behavior is just not desirable to me. I tried changing the variables in the Clojure group, but nothing seemed to work. How can I turn this behavior off?

Comment: Are you saying you want a space before 'last' (in your line 2?) If so, that is vary odd formatting choice (odd for any flavour of lisp).  You might be able to affect things with different values for clojure-indent-style, but it isn't really clear what your indent rules really are. I suspect your fighting against the mode. Other modes, like js2 tend to be more liberal because the syntax of the language is more complicated and it is harder to define consistent rules. Lisp languages have little syntax, so more rigid formatting rules. BTW why (def last (fn ...)) instead of (defn last ....)?

Comment: Are you using advanced editing capabilities like paredit or the like? I don't and for me Emacs never formats any code automatically, only when I ask it to.

Comment: @TimX given the snippet above, say if I try to insert a space before `(def`, can't happen, the space character just get deleted automatically right after the insertion. The snippet is taken from the source of clojure.core. `defn` hasn't been defined at that point :)

Comment: @StefanKamphausen Tried disabling paredit-mode, still the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the mention, my emacs.d was taken from Steve Purcell. I only changed some key bindings and the theme.

Comment: What I don't understand is why do you want to put a space before the (def? It is standard lisp style for the opening ( to be in the first column.  This is what I mean about 'fighting against the mode'. There is a standard style and while there is some accepted variation in how indentation is handled, a leading space in the manner you describe is not one of them.  I would be suprised if any of the lisp related mode would support this and I don't think there is any easy way to change this. You could not use clojure-mode, but then you would not have cider either.

Comment: One thing you could try is look at what funciton is bound to the return key. I've not checked clojure-mode, but for many modes, this is often something like newline-and-indent or something similar. It is possible that when you get to the end of the line and hit return, this function is triggering re-alignment and that is where your leading space gets removed.

Comment: @TimX Sorry, I just switched to emacs a week ago. Had no idea this is the way how clojure-mode works. Inserting a space before `(defn` is not the point. I was just trying to say I can't edit the code the way I want. And it seems to me this could be problematic like when you start to work with an open source project (that is version controlled for sure). When you open a .clj file, Emacs automatically format the code in that file, then you save—unwanted diff.

Comment: OK, have extended my answer. the use of Steve Purcell's config does have some potential impact, but I suspect your concern is really another form of premature optimisation. Your worried about a possible problem which hasn't yet been confirmed as an issue. Go with the flow for now, get to know/understand emacs and Purcell's setup and then if you find a real issue or need to tweak the config, come back and ask another quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear what you mean, but I suspect you are referring to the way
Clojure will align forms in things like let bindings so that all the symbols and
values being bound are aligned i.e.

```
(let [a-val1      (something-1)
      another-val (something-2)
      final-col   12]
  (do-some-stuff))
```

rather than

```
(let [a-val1 (something-1)
      another val (something-2)
      final-col 12]
  (do-some-stuff))
```

If this is the case, then there are a few things you can try.

Look at the variable clojure-align-forms-automatically

> clojure-align-forms-automatically is a variable defined in
>   ‘clojure-mode.el’. Its value is t Original value was nil
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>   satisfies the predicate ‘booleanp’.
>
> Documentation: If non-nil, vertically align some forms automatically.
>   Automatically means it is done as part of indenting code.  This
>   applies to binding forms (‘clojure-align-binding-forms’), to cond
>   forms (‘clojure-align-cond-forms’) and to map literals.  For instance,
>   selecting a map a hitting ‘M-x indent-for-tab-command’ will align the
>   values like this:
>       {:some-key 10
>        :key2     20}
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 5.1 of the clojure-mode package.

The other variable which you might want to look at is clojure-indent-style

> clojure-indent-style is a variable defined in ‘clojure-mode.el’. Its
>   value is ‘:always-align’
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>   satisfies the predicate ‘keywordp’.
>
> Documentation: Indentation style to use for function forms and macro
>   forms. There are two cases of interest configured by this variable.
>
> - Case (A) is when at least one function argument is on the same   line as the function name.
> - Case (B) is the opposite (no arguments are on the same line as   the function name).  Note that the body of macros is not   affected by
>     this variable, it is always indented by   ‘lisp-body-indent’ (default
>     2) spaces.
>
> Note that this variable configures the indentation of function forms
>   (and function-like macros), it does not affect macros that already use
>   special indentation rules.
>
> The possible values for this variable are keywords indicating how to
>   indent function forms.
>
> ```
> ‘:always-align’ - Follow the same rules as ‘lisp-mode’.  All
> args are vertically aligned with the first arg in case (A),
> and vertically aligned with the function name in case (B).
> For instance:
>     (reduce merge
>             some-coll)
>     (reduce
>      merge
>      some-coll)
>
> ‘:always-indent’ - All args are indented like a macro body.
>     (reduce merge
>       some-coll)
>     (reduce
>       merge
>       some-coll)
>
> ‘:align-arguments’ - Case (A) is indented like ‘lisp’, and
> case (B) is indented like a macro body.
>     (reduce merge
>             some-coll)
>     (reduce
>       merge
>       some-coll)
> ```
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 5.2.0 of the clojure-mode package.

There are some other alignment/indentation variables which you may also want to
check out - try M-x customize-group  clojure-mode and M-x customize-group
 cider to browse and see if anything is relevant. You might also find
something relevant on the cider documentation site. In particular, look at the
manual section on [indentation](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indent_spec/)

UPDATE EDIT: Based on additional information from the OP communicated in comments, I
decided to edit and extend this answer. I've left the original response as I
feel it may be useful to others who search and find the OPs question. However,
with the additional info in the comments, I don't think the answer addresses the
OPs actual issue, so have extended the answer below which I hope will help.

Some Emacs modes are more rigid or enforce code format more strictly than
others. This is particularly the case with vary *regular* languages like Clojure
(and most lisps generally) whee the syntax is minimal and the rules regarding
code indentation are easier to define and tend to have wide consensus.

The situation for the OP is further complicated because they are using a
pre-defined Emacs configuration - in this case [Steve Purcell's emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d),
which is one of my favourite pre-defined or *canned* Emacs configurations. The
one drawback with these pre-defined configurations is that they will turn on and
define many optional features of the Emacs editor which may or may not be
in-line with user personal preferences. Emacs tends to have a vary conservative
position when it comes to new features or enhancements. Often, they are disabled
by default to avoid impacting new users. The cost for this conservative approach
is that over time, Emacs can seem primitive or less feature rich compared to
other editors to new users who expect some of this behaviour to be enabled by
default. By using a canned configuration, you get one person's preferred setup
without having to go through the often long and difficult process of doing it
yourself. The downside is that when it does not match with the user's
expectations, the user does not have the knowledge or understanding to make the
changes and it is difficult to get help because others don't know/understand
what their configuration is already.

As an example how using these pre-defined setups can complicated matters, when I
last looked at the Purcell configuration, it used the ELPA package
*aggressive-indent*, which enforces more rigid indentation rules and it could
well be this package rather than clojure-mode which is enforcing the rigid
indentation rule.

The OP mentions they are concerned regarding this auto-formatting as it could
cause problems when contributing to other projects and issues with
auto-formatting making the code look like there has been more changes than has
actually occurred due to the version control picking up the whitespace
adjustments. This issue mainly comes up over differences due to the use of tabs
and spaces. to a large extent, such issues are less frequent these days as most
version control systems can be configured to ignore whitespace changes.

In this case, my recommendation is to do nothing for now as there isn't a real
issue yet. Continue to use the canned configuration and continue to ask
questions, but also spend some time trying to learn and understand the
configuration. At some point, once your comfortable with Emacs, you will likely
want to re-configure the system to better meet your own personal taste. By this
time, you will have a better understanding of Emacs, the various options it has
and the way different modes work. When you run into specific real issues which
you cannot solve, then post another question. It is likely at that point, you
will have concrete information and someone will be able to provide specific
help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind advice. The real situation is: The content of a file doesn't get re-formatted at the point when I open a file, but the enforced formatting starts to kick in when I edit the content—the lines above get outrageous (very deep) indentation, the line I'm editing shifts to the position where it is "supposed to be" by itself. I disabled aggressive-indent-mode, the situation got better, but it is still very far from the more liberal editing experience that I'm used to.

Comment: I guess this will make more sense when I'm used to the new editing experience.

Comment: I've switched to spacemacs a couple of days ago. I gotta say, the experience is much more pleasant for me, and the behavior with aggressive-indent-mode enabled is more desirable.

Comment: Yes, it shows how flexible emacs is - the same editor, but with different configurations, completely different experience. Downside can be that it can take some time to get it 'just right' and it can be difficult to get the right answer as so many variables can be involved. Glad to hear your enjoying spacemacs.

Comment: Do you use that set-up too? I discovered it just a few days ago and decided to give it a try. I think this layer thing is ace and they really get things right, at least for Clojure programming. All I did was just adding some layers and hooks, changing a couple of variables. And I really love the default key bindings. :D

Comment: No, I've looked at a few of the 'canned' configs like spacemacs, prelude and Steve Purcells' .emacs.d. and have stolen ideas from almost all of them (plus others). However, I find nothing beats a 100% your own crafted init file - I understand it beter and it does exactly what I want rather than making me adjust to what it wants.